# Splitting consecutive uppercase letters with VBA in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have the following VBA Code for Excel to find consecutive uppercase letters and split it.

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([A-Z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

The code works in the following instance:

AB Smith

AD Smith DC

Output :

> A B Smith
>
> A D Smith DC

However when there is more than 2 consecutive letters, the vba doesn't work.
I have tried using a {2,3} quantifier, however I cannot seem to get the following working:

```
SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2 $3")
```

Comment: Is the second output really `A D Smith DC`, or `A D Smith D C` ? (space between D and C)

Comment: Use a positive look-head to avoid capturing the next character:  `.Pattern = "([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])"` and `SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of three or more consecutive uppercase letters, the matches do overlap. The remedy is to apply the pattern twice in a row:

```
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([A-Z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
    SplitCaps = .Replace(SplitCaps, "$1 $2")
End With
```

Comment: thank you, this works well. is it safe to assume that if I wanted a 4th iteration, I would need to add the pattern a fourth time ?

Comment: @qbbq: No, you set the `global` flag, so two applications suffice. The first one inserts spaces after the char at an even offset from the beginning of the uppercase sequence, the second after the chars at an odd offset ( `ABCDE` -> `A BC DE` -> `A B C D E`).